# Как записать скидку к покупке в сессию? Opencart 2

Tags: php, сессия, opencart

На сайте есть кнопки для получения скидки, когда покупатель выполняет условия, то ему начисляется скидка к покупке. 
Как записать эту скидку в сессию, чтобы общая стоимость покупки была уже со скидкой. Интернет магазин на Opencart 2.

Answer (score 0):

Со скидкой где? в корзине или на категориях и на карточке?

Если на товарах в категориии или карточке . Логика следующая

Человек получил скидку - записать в сессию его индификатор ( ip например или если авторизирован то проще ) после применить при вывод категории метод, который будет считать скидку для каждого товара в массиве, как стандартный discount oc , и сдделать обновление страницы, и у пользователя будут все товары со скидкой на категории. В таком же духе нужно будет применить везде  = коризина, поиск, и т.п

Comment: Там получается, что кнопка "получить скидку" находится на всех страницах сайта. И вот как изменить сумму общей покупки после того как покупатель нажал кнопку. Я немогу найти как получить доступ к общей цены в сессии + ее изменить.

Comment: если вы не переделывали корзину, то изначально товары которые добавили в корзину хранятся в базе. Можете Открыть cart.php и посмотреть, там все методы через бд.  Индифицируется корзина , айди записывается в куки или сессию, а в базе к айди корзине накидываются товары.

Comment: можешь написать мне почту свою , и мы вместе посмотрим, я тебе покажу , как у меня будет минутка

Comment: какая у вас почта? я незнаю где посмотреть...

Comment: mydlsОдин@yandex.ru

Comment: моя почта xar4enko11@gmail.com